# Every vector of a linearly independent set can be expressed in Span of that set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B = \{\vec v_1, ..., \vec v_n\}$ be a linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Prove that every vector in $SpanB$ can be written as a unique linear combination of vectors in $B$.

Comment: Can you recall the definition of $\operatorname{span}{(B)}?$

Answer (score 2):

For $M$ a subset of your vector space, $\operatorname{Span}M$ is by definition the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $M$. So in your situation, every vector $v$ in $\operatorname{Span}B$ is a linear combination of vectors in $B$, so it remains to show that the linear combination is unique. Let $v=\sum_i\lambda_iv_i=\sum_i\mu_iv_j$ be two such linear combinations, then $$0=v-v=\sum_i\lambda_iv_i-\sum_i\mu_iv_i=\sum_i(\lambda_i-\mu_i)v_i,$$
but $B$ is linearly independent, hence $\lambda_i-\mu_i=0$ for all $i$. This means $\lambda_i=\mu_i$ for all $i$, so the two linear combinations of $v$ are the same one, showing that it is unique.